# Preloading Animation hides all the cool slider intro animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I coded a website in HTML5 recently. Its slider have some cool intro animations (used slider revolution plugin for slider intro animations). Then I installed a preloading animation on the website (this one - ihatetomatoes[dot]net/demos/css3-preloader-transition). All works perfectly. But the cool and awesome animations of the slider are already over when the preloader finishes and takes us the to website.

Code to slider animations: http://pastebin.com/HTVGxpCz
Code to the preloader: http://pastebin.com/14JPCX1n

Please help me so that site loads perfectly -- preloader loads, then when it ends, only then do the slider intro animations start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the that by initializing revolution slider once you execute the code to remove
loader from screen.

Hopefully this should work for the loader issue.